# PGAdmin3 showing two databases from same port - How to remove?

Tags: postgresql

I uninstalled and reinstalled postgres, deleted data, but this issue still exists. For some reason, it keeps showing a database using 8.4 (even though the version number is 9.0 as confirmed by pgadmin3.

How do I get rid of this 8.4 DB?

Here's a screenshot: http://imageupload.org/?d=4D9F98A51
And another: http://imageupload.org/?d=4D9F99391

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

List of servers displayed by pgAdmin is (on OSX) located in:

```
~/Library/Preferences/pgadmin3 Preferences
```

Have fun editing this file manually :)

Look for a line Description=PostgreSQL 8.4 it will be included in a section called something like [Servers/1] or [Servers/2] remove the whole section and all sections called [Servers/n/*]

Comment: I don't have this file. Can't find it.

Comment: You know ~ means your home directory on UNIX systems?

Answer (score 0):

Select it first, then delete it?

**Later . . .**

Looks like a [bug in pgadmin3](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/cannot-remove-some-items-from-the-server-list-after-upgrade-from-postgres-8-x-to-9-x-td3334788.html). The suggestion seems to be moving in the direction of deleting a key from the registry on Windows. I'm not sure whether that will be in your preferences on OSX.

Comment: Done that multiple times on both.

Comment: That's a version 8.4 server, by the way, not an 8.4 database.